# Java padding performance busting

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, false-sharing

Hi Guys so i got this piece of code

```
public class Padding {

  static class Pair {

        volatile long c1;
        // UN-comment this line and see how perofmance is boosted * 2
      //  long q1; //Magic dodo thingy

        volatile long c2;

  }

  static Pair p = new Pair();

  static class Worker implements Runnable {

        private static final int INT = Integer.MAX_VALUE/8;
        private boolean b;
        Worker(boolean b) {
              this.b = b;
        }

        public void run() {
              long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
              if (b) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < INT; i++) {
                          p.c1++;
                          res += Math.random();
                    }
              } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < INT; i++) {
                          p.c2++;
                          res += Math.random();
                    }
              }
              long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
              System.out.println("took: " + (end-start) + " Result:" + p.c1+p.c2);
        }

  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting....");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker(true));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Worker(false));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();


  }
```

}

So if i run it takes about 11 seconds but if i uncomment qa1 it runs in 3 second .I tried to find some thing on internet but nothing informative enough came up. As i understand it has some thing to do with JVM optimiztion and long q1 probably makes memory (or cache) distribution some how better . Any way my question is does some one knows where can i read about it more .
Thanks

Comment: Where are you referring the `q1` variable?

Comment: Where do you declare `res`?

Comment: Thats the thihng you dont currently it is commented out in line 4 but if uncomment it the magic hapens

Answer (score 10):

Performance in your example is degradated by [false sharing](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ru/2011/07/false-sharing.html) - `c1` and `c2` instances are placed in the same cache line and threads need to flush/load values to/from main memory at every increment of *different* fields to maintain cache coherency after mututal cache line copy invalidation.

In your case it is enough to declare one more `q1` long field right after `c1` to make `c2` go to another cache line (which size is only `64 bytes` for the `x86` family). After it cache management becomes way more efficient - threads can use different cache lines and do not invalidate copy of the other thread's cache line.

There are many articles which are devoted to the hardware nature of this issue (and software ways of avoiding it). Dealing with false sharing by "footprint padding" solution (like yours) has been being tricky for a long time - Java platform **doesn't** guarantee that fields order and cache line padding in runtime would be exactly as your expect in class declaration. Even "minor" platfrom update or switch to another VM implementation can brake a solution (because fields - especially unused dummies - are subjects of optimizations).

That's whу [JEP-142](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/142) was introduced and `@Contended` annotation [was implemented](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2012-November/007309.html) in `Java 8`. This annotation allows you to configure which fields of the class should be placed on different cache lines.
But now it's just a VM hint without any absolute guarantee about false sharing avoidance in all situations, so you should look at your code carefully and verify its behaviour (if your application is sensitive to the false sharing issue, of course)